# No hyphenation patterns were preloaded

Tags: languages, hyphenation, french

I have a problem with a document I'm writing and I found no suitable response to my problem:

```
Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for
(babel)                the language `French' into the format.
(babel)                Please, configure your TeX system to add them and
(babel)                rebuild the format. Now I will use the patterns
(babel)                preloaded for \language=nohyphenation instead on input line 56.
```

Here is what I put on the document:

```
\documentclass[final]{report}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

I use `pdflatex` on Fedora 23. I have correctly install `texlive-lang-french` and `texlive-hyphen-french`.

Comment: Try running (as superuser) `mktexfmt --all`

Comment: Thanks ! I tried `mktexfmt --all` but I had `fmtutil: unknown option --all, try --help.`.
So I launched `fmutil --all` and `fmtutil-sys --all` as root but I always have the problem.

Comment: So when you ran `sudo mktexfmt --all` it complained that `--all` was an unknown option for `fmtutil`, but then you ran `sudo fmtutil --all` ? That doesn't make sense. I would recommend ditching Fedora's TeX Live packages and installing TeX Live from upstream. All you need is a small dummy package to keep the package manager happy, and it will all work beautifully. Distro's packagings of TeX Live are not always entirely happy ones.

Comment: Sounds really weird to mee too. I'll try to install it from source... Thanks for your response.

Comment: `fmtutil` is the local version of `fmtutil-sys`. For some strange reason (at least on Fedora 24). `fmtutil` does not accept `--all` as an option for rebuilding files. However, using `fmtutil --missing --refresh` should do virtually the same thing and fixes the hyphenation problem for me.

Comment: With texlive2021, `sudo fmtutil-sys --all` worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem on Fedora 29. `texlive-lang-french` and `texlive-hyphen-french` were installed, but hyphenation did not work.

I found a solution on [Red Hat Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1595165#c3): to remove the directory `~/.texlive2018`.

> Removing the directory ~/.texlive2018 and using the latest version of texlive solved the problem. This directory has been created by some previous execution of pdflatex (already on Fedora 29, because I installed from scratch), but maybe before the hyphenation packages had been installed. Further tests are needed to determine if the bug persists in the latest version when a user installs the hyphenation packages after ~/.texlive2018 has been created.

Comment: on Fedora 34 : $ rm -rf ~./texlive2020 worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I found out what was the problem (and I'll try to explain what I understood) : On Fedora, hyphenations files are located to `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/*` and seems not to be the real location/name for hyphenation files.

Adding `hyphsubst` seems to authorize pdflatex to load hyphenation files from unusual places. So when I added it, it worked !

I'm not sure it's the real reason but if someone has a better explanation : you can contradict me with pleasure ;)

Long story, short story, I added :

```
\usepackage{hyphsubst}
```

Comment: fwiw, I'm also on Fedora (25) and have the same problem, but this didn't help in my case.

Comment: I cannot find this package on MikTex 2.9. Does it exists?

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue on *openSUSE Tumbleweed*. The **force reinstall** of `texlive-hyphen-czech` helped me in my case. It looks like `texlive` sometimes [loses files during a package update](https://translate.google.cz/translate?sl=cs&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=cs&ie=UTF-8&u=https:%2F%2Flists.felk.cvut.cz%2Fpipermail%2Fcstex%2F2015-May%2F025550.html).

```
$ zypper in -f texlive-babel-czech texlive-hyphen-czech texlive-cs-fonts texlive-csbulletin texlive-texlive-cz texlive-cslatex-bin texlive-cs texlive-cslatex
```

I did full reinstall of *Czech* related packages in my case, so I can't tell if it's caused only by `texlive-hyphen-czech`.

Comment: This solution also works on Fedora 36 (with `dnf` of course). In my case, I used `sudo dnf install texlive-hyphen-german`

Comment: I had this problem too. The above solution worked for me as well. And then for good measure ```rm -rf ~/.texlive*``` and ```fmtutil-sys --all```. And you guessed right ... Fedora too ... bummer

Answer (score 2):

To summarize, assuming that the required packages have been installed (for example with Fedora's `dnf`), the TeX formats are updated with

```
sudo fmtutil-sys --all
```

and `fmtutil-user` should not be used in general as explained [here](https://tug.org/texlive/scripts-sys-user.html).