# F25/TexLive2016 No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for the language Russian

Tags: texlive, hyphenation, russian

sorry for asking a question which arised many times here. I read all respective threads and nothing helped.

My OS is Fedora 25, TexLive 2016. The code (ruhyphen.tex) is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyphsubst}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\begin{document}
Привет
\end{document}
```

The output of the latex command is:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./ruhyphen.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 3 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hyphsubst.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2aenc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2acmr.fd))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t2aenc.dfu)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-russian/russianb.ldf

Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for
(babel)                the language `Russian' into the format.
(babel)                Please, configure your TeX system to add them and
(babel)                rebuild the format. Now I will use the patterns
(babel)                preloaded for english instead on input line 26.

)) (./ruhyphen.aux) [1] (./ruhyphen.aux) )
Output written on ruhyphen.dvi (1 page, 232 bytes).
Transcript written on ruhyphen.log.
```

The packages installed:

```
texlive-babel-russian-svn39784-22.fc25.1.noarch
texlive-hyphen-russian-svn40340-22.fc25.1.noarch
texlive-lshort-russian-doc-svn18906.0-22.fc25.1.noarch
texlive-ruhyphen-svn21081.1.6-22.fc25.1.noarch
```

After installation of these, I run fmtutil-sys --all. The output suggests that the hyphen files were processed:

```
...
Preloading the plain format: codes, registers, parameters, fonts, more fonts,
macros, math definitions, output routines, hyphenation
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyphen/hyphen.tex
...
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyphen/hyphen.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadhyph-ru.tex
UTF-8 Russian hyphenation patterns
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-ru.tex))
...
```

In the thread [No hyphenation patterns were preloaded](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284168/no-hyphenation-patterns-were-preloaded) Lerenn wrote that the problem with Fedora was possibly that the /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph directory is not standard and that including

```
\usepackage{hyphsubst}
```

solved his problem. In my case this does not change anything.

Any help would be welcome.
Thanks,
Igor

Comment: it works for me but your format seems very wrong `Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 3 language(s) loaded.` with an up to date tl2016 I get  `Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded` The log you show of a format is of plain tex fomat, can you show the log from making latex.fmt

Comment: @David Carliste Thanks for the answer. Yes, the hyphenetion patterns for only 3 languages confused me, too. As for the log you are asking about, sorry I don't quite understand - do you mean the full output of fmtutil-sys --all ?

Comment: The usual suggestion is to install vanilla TeXlive. If you insist on using the packages from somewhere else, please file bug reports there.

Comment: fmtutil should have left a latex.log wherver it's configured to build the formats `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/latex.log` for me

Comment: @Martin I am trying to avoid installing vanilla version. I have to manage several F25 computers, breaking the standard dnf management would lead to various troubles...

Comment: @David In F25 latex.log is in /var/lib/texmf/web2c/pdftex/latex.log. The file is too long to present it here. Here is the link: http://dionis.sai.msu.ru/~igor/latex.log What is suspicious is that there are many hyphen exceptions in this file.

Comment: look at the file `kpsewhich language.dat` (`/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.dat` in vanilla` that should have the lines for Russian not commented.....)

Comment: @David Thanks a lot! The problem is solved. Explanation is too long for a comment so I updated the original post.

Comment: @Igor Please post the resolution as an answer (and remove from the question): the site structure is Q&A, so to help future readers the questions and answers should be separate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because theissue was due the a stray file in the system.

Comment: @Joseph - Sorry, I am new to the forum, did not pay attention to the "Answer your question" button.  I added the answer and edited the original post. Thanks.

Comment: @egreg It was not clear to me when I posted the question what was the reason for the problem. It might be package or texlive - related. the question may be off-topic in regard to texlive. But it is was a real problem so I think keeping this thread here can help others who encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to David's comments, the issue is resolved. In F25, there are 2 language.dat files:

```
/etc/texlive/tex/generic/config/language.dat
```

and

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/config/language.dat
```

The former does not contain russian lines. The latter does:

```
russian loadhyph-ru.tex
```

Following the pattern for english in the /etc/.../language.dat file I added the lines to it

```
russian ruhyphen.tex
=userussian
```

After that, I run "fmtutil-sys --all". And this worked! babel tells me that hyphenation patterns were loaded for 12 languages and did not complain about Russian. So it must be a bug in F25 texlive packaging. Installing Russian components should update the /etc/.../language.dat file but it does not. The header of the file says "Do not edit manually, the file is generated by tlmgr". But tlmgr is excluded from F25 texlive package and not available in any repos. The reason is Fedora does not want any package to be maintained outside the official package manager dnf (which is reasonable). If only they did their packaging properly... Anyway, the issue can be closed. Thanks a lot to all of you.